# How does Storm's OutputCollector work?

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

This is with reference to [Storm's OutputCollector](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/task/OutputCollector.java#L211-L220) and its `ack(Tuple)` and `fail(Tuple)` methods in particular.

Both these methods just transfer the call to `_delegate` field of type `IOutputCollector`.

But on seeing the type hierarchy of [IOutputCollector](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/task/IOutputCollector.java), it doesn't seem like there is any class implementing that interface which can do something useful with these methods.

`CoordinatedOutputCollector` and `AnchoringOutputCollector` seem to be doing something specific to their own use-cases.

If I run a topology with at-least once delivery semantics with acknowledged Tuples, what kind of output collector is used?

Or more generally, how does an OutputCollector work in Storm?

When Tuples are sent from one executor to another, there are LMAX-disruptor queues and netty-callbacks involved. But tuple-progression is like a forward flow, while `ack()`/`fail()` are backward flows (because `(N+1)th` bolt acks/fails tuples to its preceding `Nth` bolt, all the way upto the Spout).

Is there a good tutorial/blog on how that works using OutputCollectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BoltOutputCollectorImpl](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/executor/bolt/BoltOutputCollectorImpl.java) is what you are looking for. Both `ack` and `fail` messages are sent to the [Acker bolt](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/daemon/Acker.java). When Acker has received acks from all bolts in time, it will send an ack message to spout; otherwise, it will send back a fail message.

You may also want to checkout [SpoutOutputCollectorImpl](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/executor/spout/SpoutOutputCollectorImpl.java), [SpoutExecutor](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/executor/spout/SpoutExecutor.java) and [BoltExecutor](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/executor/bolt/BoltExecutor.java) for the complete flow.

Note the above links are from Apache Storm trunk which is of version 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and not yet released. For previous Storm versions, implementations of `OutputCollector` are in Clojure.